# Swift: Resize NavigationBar for iPad Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar which looks perfect on iphone devices but when opened in an iPad it appears very small. i'm using storyboard to design, how can i resize the navigation bar and it's font for ipad.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The height of Navigation bar is Fixed to 65 with status bar.
but if you want to change the haight of navigation bar you can do the following alternative way.

```
let height: CGFloat = 50 //whatever height you want to add to the existing height
let bounds = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height + height)
```

and for setting font.

```
if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
        {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName :NavigationColor,
                                                                NSFontAttributeName: FontLight_40
            ]
            UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:FontLight_40], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        else
        {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName :NavigationColor,
                                                                NSFontAttributeName: FontLight_20
            ]
            UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:FontLight_20], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work in iOS 11. Any other solution?

Comment: @gsp1294 Please make a try this will work. I also used same for font purpose and I am sure it will work for height too.

Comment: I tried, It's not working. Did this work for iOS 11?